# Editing Built In Volume Oscillator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hacking my way through but just not getting it.

I have the built in Volume Oscillator which works great, but I'd like to change it (of course). I'd like it to print a background color on the chart, for each bar that shows above the 0 (zero) line.

I could post all of the different error messages, but it seems like I'm just going around in circles.

This is TradingView's code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Volume Oscillator", shorttitle="Volume Osc", format=format.percent, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

// Setup Variables
var cumVol = 0.
cumVol += nz(volume)
if barstate.islast and cumVol == 0
    runtime.error("No volume is provided by the data vendor.")
    
// User input
shortlen = input.int(5, minval=1, title = "Short Length")
longlen = input.int(10, minval=1, title = "Long Length")

// Calculate data
short = ta.ema(volume, shortlen)
long = ta.ema(volume, longlen)
osc = 100 * (short - long) / long

// Plot data
hline(0, color = #787B86, title="Zero")
plot(osc, color=#2962FF)
```

Comment: Never mind. Got it. Whew.
Now to work on the next problem.
Here is the answer if you want it.

Was simple.

signalBS = (osc > 0)

// Plot data
bgcolor(signalBS ? color.green : na, title = "Column color")

Answer (score 0):

Well, `osc` has the value you are looking for. Use a variable to check if it is above the zero and then use that variable to change the background color.

```
osc_abv = (osc > 0)
bgcolor(osc_abv ? color.new(color.green, 85) : na)
```